# SQL query for the below

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sequelpro

Table A has the current `ValueA` and `ValueB`:

```
Token     ValueA     ValueB 
ABC        SHOP Val1      
DEF        SHOP         Val2
GHI         SHIPP        Val3
JKL         SHIPP         Val2
```

Table B has all the data transitions:

```
Token      Value         Value2         Date                         Express
ABC     SHOP    Val1               2020-01-01             Yes
ABC.        SHOP       Val2               2020-02-01             Yes
ABC         SHIPP.      Val3               2020-03-01              Yes 
DEF          SHOP       Val1               2020-05-01               No
DEF          SHIPP       Val2               2020-04-01              No
DEF          SHIPP.      Val3               2020-03-01               No
```

I expect that my result should include the latest data from TableA but add specific dates from TableB:

```
Token     ValueA       Val1 Date       Val2 Date
ABC        SHOP . 2020-01-01       2020-02-01
DEF        SHOP          2020-05-01.      2020-04-01   
GHI         SHIPP         NULL          NULL
JKL         SHIPP        NULL           NULL
```

My query is not returning the result as I expected:

```
SELECT a.token,
              A.valueA,
              A.valueB,
              B.Express
       c.Date "SHOP DATE",
       d.Date “SHIP DATE"
FROM TableA A 
LEFT JOIN TABLEB B ON A.Token = B.Token
LEFT JOIN TABLEB C ON A.Token = B.Token
LEFT JOIN TABLEB D ON A.Token = B.Token
WHERE (c.value = ‘SHOP’ AND c.value2 = ‘Val1’)
  AND (c.value = ‘SHIP’ AND c.value2 = ‘Val13)
GROUP BY a.token
ORDER BY b.date DESC;
```

Query result:

```
Token     ValueA       Val1 Date       Val2 Date
ABC        SHOP . 2020-01-01       2020-02-01
DEF        SHOP          2020-05-01.      2020-04-01
```

Comment: Note: The [tag:sequel] tag applies to the Ruby ORM only. Also, please put in the effort to come up with a much more descriptive title. See "[ask]" and its linked pages. "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `WHERE` condition inside `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.token,
              A.valueA,
              A.valueB,
              B.Express
       c.Date "SHOP DATE",
       d.Date "SHIP DATE"
FROM TableA A 
LEFT JOIN TABLEB B 
ON A.Token = B.Token

LEFT JOIN TABLEB C 
ON A.Token = B.Token
AND c.value = 'SHOP' AND c.value2 = 'Val1'
AND c.value = 'SHIP' AND c.value2 = 'Val3'

LEFT JOIN TABLEB D 
ON A.Token = B.Token

GROUP BY a.token
ORDER BY b.date DESC;
```